# Why is Postgres full table scan so slow?

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-optimization, database-performance

I am testing the performance of Postgres full table scans (no index), and it's surprisingly slow.

The following is run on a fresh db.m5.8xlarge box from AWS:

```
CREATE TABLE test100m AS SELECT * FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, 100000000) AS id;

SET max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 6;

EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT max(id) FROM test100m;
```

Result:

```
                                                                    QUERY PLAN                                                                    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Finalize Aggregate  (cost=651812.03..651812.04 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=1817.850..1819.931 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Gather  (cost=651811.40..651812.01 rows=6 width=4) (actual time=1817.788..1819.921 rows=7 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 6
         Workers Launched: 6
         ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=650811.40..650811.41 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=1814.193..1814.194 rows=1 loops=7)
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on test100m  (cost=0.00..609144.72 rows=16666672 width=4) (actual time=0.003..902.986 rows=14285714 loops=7)
 Planning Time: 0.055 ms
 Execution Time: 1819.953 ms
```

So, 1800ms to scan 100M rows. On my laptop (limited to 6 cores, with similar performance as db.m5.8xlarge), scanning 100M array entries takes 38ms:

```
func TestTiming(t *testing.T) {
    {
        data := make([]int, 100000000)
        for i := 0; i < len(data); i++ {
            data[i] = i
        }
        start := time.Now()
        max := data[0]
        for i := 0; i < len(data); i++ {
            if max < data[i] {
                max = data[i]
            }
        }
        fmt.Printf("Timing: 100,000,000 %s\n", time.Since(start))
    }
}
```

That's a difference of ~50 times. Granted I am not comparing apples to apples here, but still I would've expected a much smaller difference in performance. All data easily fits in memory.

Can Postgres performance on full table scans be significantly improved somehow? (besides increasing max_parallel_workers_per_gather) What is it doing to be 50x slower?

UPDATE:

Including a more detailed query plan:

```
> EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, TIMING) SELECT max(id) FROM test100m;


                                                                    QUERY PLAN                                                                    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Finalize Aggregate  (cost=651812.03..651812.04 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=1953.561..1955.891 rows=1 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=442478
   ->  Gather  (cost=651811.40..651812.01 rows=6 width=4) (actual time=1953.505..1955.885 rows=7 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 6
         Workers Launched: 6
         Buffers: shared hit=442478
         ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=650811.40..650811.41 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=1950.497..1950.497 rows=1 loops=7)
               Buffers: shared hit=442478
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on test100m  (cost=0.00..609144.72 rows=16666672 width=4) (actual time=0.004..916.197 rows=14285714 loops=7)
                     Buffers: shared hit=442478
 Planning Time: 0.059 ms
 Execution Time: 1955.916 ms
```

Comment: Please turn on `track_io_timing` then show us the execution plan generated using `explain (analyze, buffers, timing)`. I wouldn't be surprised if your hosting platform limits I/O in some way.

Comment: Note that your code does not do _any_ I/O from disk, so it has not relevance at all.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I included a more detailed query plan. But the data set is small, there is no I/O here.

Comment: Shrug. It's probably AWS. On a 8 year old desktop (4 physical CPUs, 8 with multi-threading) with a spinning hard disk, this takes about 3.8 seconds. But only half of the data comes from the cache.

Comment: I have no idea what language that second one is.  Does it have a multithreading mode in which you could make it need to lock and unlock every thing it accesses to make it concurrency safe?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name This is strange. On a recent laptop "Ryzen 7 PRO 5850U" with 16GiB RAM, Fedora 36, distribution-included PostgreSQL 14.3 and 6 workers (100% CPU on 7 postmaster processes), I'm consistently getting 34s, not 4s.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name But when run without "explain analyze", then it took 1.6s. While doing "explain analyze" linux "perf" showed over 57% of read_hpet, 32% of copy_user_enhanced_fast_string. It seems that checking the time for "analyze" is taking so long.

Comment: `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` slows things down. What you shouldn't forget in your comparison is that a PostgreSQL table row has a header of 23 bytes in addition to the 4 bytes of an `integer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

50 times difference, as compared to just scanning an array in memory, is not that strange. Just imagine what the database needs to do:

- check if the needed block of data is in the cache (supposedly using some complicated algorithm, some locking to avoid race conditions etc.);
- parse each 8kiB block of data and convert it to some in-memory storage format;
- check each row of this in-memory storage format, if it is visible by current transaction (another complicated algorithm, needed to avoid problems caused by wrap-around of transaction id);
- apply some internal representation of a query plan on each row, which is way more complicated than just comparing two integers;
- gather results from all parallel workers, which requires quite a lot of locking and synchronization to avoid corrupting memory;
- merge results of parallel query, using another complicated algorithm with locking etc.

And this is still way simplified.

Comment: Right, I am not downplaying the complexities of what the DB does. Still, the performance difference is a bit shocking. If I have to run say a thousand of these full table scans, it would be faster to get a few gigs of data to an instance and run the algorithm there, rather than on DB.

Comment: Yes, it would. Even when you store the data in the db, and just query it with "select * from test100m", and then run your algorithm locally on an array a few times, it will be much faster. Even if your data is larger than RAM, then piping a CSV file through a program, would be much faster. Database strengths are different, like parallel read-write access, updating a particular row etc.

Comment: When you create a table in PostgreSQL, all 100M of the table's data is written to hard disk. And when you want to get max(id) then 100M data is read from the disk. But, arrays stores in virtual memory (RAM), not in HDD and operations on it must of course be fast

Comment: @RaminFaracov The dataset is small and is fully in memory. You can see that from the EXPLAIN BUFFERS command output in my question.